# Is it secure to put all of your ASP.NET web apps under the same website in IIS (e.g. Default Website)? (more inside)

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, iis-8

I am going to need to host multiple websites in IIS, but will not have separate URLs setup in DNS for each one.  Because of this, I will not be able to use the Aias/CNAME functionality in IIS to redirect traffic to individual Websites in IIS.

Would it be secure enough to publish all of my web apps to the same Website in IIS?

Example: under Default Website, there is a folder for each individual web app:

```
-Default Website
--[folder for webapp1]
--[folder for webapp2]
--[folder for webapp3]
```

URLs used to access each web app:

```
www.mydomain.com/webapp1
www.mydomain.com/webapp2
www.mydomain.com/webapp3
```

Is this sort of setup secure or a good idea (best practices)?  It seems like a simple solution to the problem of not having a separate domain name in DNS for every web app (website).

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with that approach, in a way it does simplify things quite a bit actually.

Sites being secure is not going to be affected by this. Of course each application would be under it's own pool, it's always a great idea to run like this.

This being said, your main website is going to run under it's own application pool and if there is a problem with it all your applications will be affected. That's the one thing I would pay extra attention to so you might want to not actually use that top level app pool for anything.